# Zend db table find just like fetchRow

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

I´m using find() to retrieve a value from the database, but It returns an array with the objects, I would like that it return to me just the object like fetchRow returns, is there any change or similar thing to do?

Thanks, and best regard´s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, It was so simple, for those that are in doubt, the solution is:

`Zend_Loader::loadClass('News');`

```
$db = new News();
$row = $db->find($id)->current();
```

That´s it, thanks.